# Does getter mettod .attr() modifies associated data with element?

Tags: d3.js

Accessing an element's property modifies the associated data? I have a 'rect' element with an array associated with it, e.g. ["name", 0, 10], when I access this rect element to get its width - using d3.select("rect").attr("width") - the data associated with it changes to just the first element of the array, i.e., "name".
Does accessing an element through .select, or access property of an element through .attr modifies the **data** property?

Comment: Data is not altered by attr. Can you create an example/snippet of the behavior you describe?